# How do I define my own notation for mixed operators?

Tags: custom-notation, notation

The built in Plus and Times operators when rendered behave the following way:

```
Plus[a,b,Times[-1,c],d]
```

> `a + b - c + d`

Basically as I see Times forces Plus to omit the "+" character before "-c".

#### Question

How to define for my own two functions a notation which renders a form such as

```
op1[a, b, op2[c], d]
```

as

> `a op1 b op2[c] op1 d`

Comment: Is there really nothing between `b` and `c`?

Comment: @Mathe172 yes, as there is nothing between 'b' and '-c'

Comment: But then inputting `a op1 b c op1 d` will be equivalent to `op1[a,b*c,d]`, or am I missing something? Or should it not be possible to input anything using this notation?

Comment: @Mathe172 true that, I only thought about formatting the output, edited the question

Answer (score 4):

The best way IMO is not to change anything in the way the expressions are stored, but only to change the way they are printed. We can do this by defining a small command, **minus[a]**, which is simply printed with the extra minus sign. We can then switch each occurrence of **Times[-1,a]** with this command *after* the expressions are evaluated but *before* they are printed. We can do this with **\$PrePrint** command.

The code:

```
$PrePrint = # //. Times[-1, a_] :> minus[a] &;
Format[minus[a_]] := -a;
```

Example:

```
expression = a - b;
expression

(* a + -b *)
```

Since we are only effecting the expressions  *after* they are evaluated, the command *minus* is actually not in the expressions, so they work as expected:

```
expression+b
(* a *)
```

Above simple code can be further generalized to ensure that any manifestly negative expression is printed as OP wanted, not just those of the form **Times[-1,a]**. To do this, we simply do as follows:

```
$PrePrint = # //. {
  Times[a___, b_?Negative, c___] :> minus[Abs@b, a, c], 
  Times[a___, Complex[0, b_?Negative], c___] :> minus[Complex[0, Abs@b], a, c]
  } //. Complex[0, b_?Negative] :> minus[Complex[0, Abs@b]] &;
Format[minus[a_, b___]] := -Times[a, b];
```

Now, we can get any expression with an explicit overall minus sign in the required printed form.

Examples:

```
expr = {a - b, a + b - 2 c, a - Pi, a - 3 I , a - I b}; expr

(* {a + -b, a + b + -2 c, a + -\[Pi], a + -3 I, a + -I b} *)
```

Note that the code is only about printing, so it does not interfere with evaluation. Hence, for example, for $a-2a$, you would get $-a$, *not* $a+-2a$! Also, if a numeric number is not purely real or purely imaginary, the code does not do anything; for example

```
exp = a - 1 + I; exp

(* (-1 + I) + a *)
```

The code did not change $(-1+I)$ to $-(1-I)$ as this numeric number is neither purely real nor purely imaginary!

Answer (score 3):

Here is one possible solution:

*Note*: I'll be using `⊕`/`⊖` (respectively `oplus`/`ominus`) to recreate the effect of `+`/`-` - change operators/symbols as necessary

First, use [`InfixNotation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Notation/ref/InfixNotation.html)  to get the foundation:

```
InfixNotation[ParsedBoxWrapper["⊕"], oplus]
InfixNotation[ParsedBoxWrapper["⊖"], ominus]
Attributes[oplus] = {Flat, OneIdentity};
Attributes[ominus] = {Flat, OneIdentity};
```

This gets us to here:

```
a⊕b⊖c⊖c⊕d // FullForm
(* oplus[a,ominus[b,c,c],d] *)
```

Next, transform `ominus[…]` into something more similar to `Plus[a,Times[-1,b]]`:

```
ominus[a_, b__] := oplus[a, Sequence @@ Map[oinv, {b}]]
```

Giving us:

```
a⊕b⊖c⊖c⊕d // FullForm
(* oplus[a,b,oinv[c],oinv[c],d] *)
```

So input is already working. Output formatting still has some issues though:

```
oplus[a,b,oinv[c],oinv[c],d]
(* a⊕b⊕oinv[c]⊕oinv[c]⊕d *)
```

Basically, we need to replace `⊕oinv[…]` with `⊖…`. The following should achieve this (hopefully) robustly:

```
NotationMakeBoxes[oplus[arg1_, args__], StandardForm] /; MemberQ[$ContextPath, "Global`"]:=
  RowBox@Riffle[
   List @@ (
     FixedPoint[
         Replace[
          HoldComplete[pre___, unproc@bef_, Longest[inv : unproc@oinv[_] ..], post___] :>
              HoldComplete[pre, ominus[bef, inv], post]
          ],
         unproc /@ HoldComplete[arg1, args]
         ] //. HoldPattern@ominus[pre___, unproc@oinv[inv_], post___] :>
              ominus[pre, inv, post] 
           /. om_ominus :> MakeBoxes[om, StandardForm] 
           /. unproc@arg_ :> Parenthesize[arg, StandardForm, CirclePlus]
     ),
   "⊕"
   ]
```

First, lets verify that it works:

```
oplus[a,b,oinv[c],oinv[c],d]
(* a⊕b⊖c⊖c⊕d *)
```

#### How it works

The basic idea is to override the formatting rule put in place by `InfixNotation` and replace it with something that knows how to handle `oinv[…]`:

- First wrap the args in `HoldComplete` and wrap all arguments in `unproc`, to keep track of which arguments need processing at the end.
- Then, we replace argument sequences of the form `unproc@arg1,unproc@oinv[arg2],unproc@oinv[arg3],…` with `ominus[arg1,unproc@oinv@arg2,unproc@oinv@arg3,…]` (since we are within `HoldComplete` this is not reverted)
- Then, we remove the `unproc@oinv@` wrappers within all `ominus`
- Then, we call the existing (thanks to `InfixNotation`) formatter for `ominus`
- And finally, we format the remain `unproc` arguments using the default formatting routine